# Saving from Layout Manger makes Map area blacked out using QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, layouts

I have been composing a number of layout from a project in QGIS.  These have all exported with no issue.  But today I have encountered a problem when exporting as an image, pdf and SVG that I can not resolve.  One of my maps boxes appears blacked out (see below for what the output should look like and what I am getting when I export).

[image: This is what the layout should look like. The large frame in the top left is where I am having the issue. This is map frame of a section of my project area with a smaller insert of a larger area of the project]

[image: This is what the exported layout looks like. You can see the large map frame which appears blacked out with the smaller inset map visble]

I have tried saving in different file formates and also tried deleting the map frame and then reinstalling it.  The rectangle in the top left has two map frames.  Originally both of these map frames appeared as black but after re-adding the large frame and redoing the overview for the smaller insert map the smaller map frame is now visible when I try to export.  I have tried adding an overview to the larger frame but this does not make any difference and the large frame remains blacked out.

I am new to QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Could you give us more information as to what sort of data is in your map frame? Is there a web map baselayer that is messing up export at a particular resolution, perhaps? Does it work if you turn off one of the layers?

Comment: Box a) is a combination vector basemap (from Natural Earth) with an SRTM overlay using the hillshade function to generate the mountain range.  Becasue the base map is vector I don't think it should be a zoom issue but to double check I have zoomed out and tried saving it again and still have the black box.  Just to clarify I have been able to save another map showing these same layer and a at a similar zoom with no issues